# What would be involved in disconnecting one set of controls in an aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-controls, engineering

Every aircraft I've seen has two sets of controls, even aircraft with only two seats. For any number of reasons - we'll go with "This pre-teen is super excited about aviation and wants to fly, but has motor control issues" - a pilot may find themselves with a passenger who can't be trusted to not fuss with those controls.

My understanding is that in anything that isn't fly-by-wire, those controls are mechanically/physically bound together (along with the control surfaces), so I assume there's no cutoff lever that would allow the PIC to positively assert control over the aircraft.

With that understanding, what would the process be to (legally in the U.S., and ideally reversibly) disconnect the controls for one seat?

Obviously each aircraft's mechanical specifics will vary, so the physical part of the job should be summarized but I'm interested to know if such modifications (which presumably don't meaningfully alter the weight and balance) automatically require the aircraft to be registered as Experimental and whether or not this would be mechanically straightforward or a massive undertaking.

EDIT in response to comment:

If a specific plane is required for your answer, assume a Piper J-3 Cub or some other fore-and-aft seater where a rambunctious passenger couldn't just lean over and grab the PIC's controls.  If there are specific aircraft where this is easier to effect than others, that's also interesting and should be included in an answer.

Comment: Since you seem to have a specific aircraft (type) in mind, perhaps you should tell us what airplane you want to do this in -- it's very different in a Piper Cub than a Cessna 152, for instance...

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'm not actually specifically thinking of any particular aircraft, but if there's a plane where this would be easier than most that's interesting information for me.  I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: I personally would not mind seeing answers for different GA planes. This is an interesting question.

Comment: The PA-15 Vagabond only had 1 set of controls. It's like a Cub with side by side seats.

Comment: Highly related!  -- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/53864/34686

Comment: OK, what's the famous story, published in a well-known aviation autobiography, can't bring it to mind right now.  AT-6 Texan had control sticks that could be removed.  One particular instructor pilot (flying from back) was famous for signalling to students that he trusted their judgement and was about ready to let them solo, by unbolting his control stick and tossing it overboard out past the sliding canopy.  Students decided to play a joke-- hid a spare control stick in front cockpit-- when instructor threw his stick overboard, student feigned a puzzled questioning expression, then did same!

Comment: Hopefully the plane in question does not also have engine controls, fuel shutoff, avionics, etc. within reach of the untrusted person? If so, I don't think it would be wise to take this person flying if they can't be trusted to not mess with the controls. Engine suddenly quitting when pax gets excited right after plane takes off would really ruin your day.

Comment: This is at least going sideways, and is removing the second set of controls a purely mechanical issue? Isn't dual control a legal requirement for safety reasons… else why would manufacturers not offer cheaper, solo variants? Further, in a tiny little two-seater, is it certain the pre-teen passenger who can't be trusted not to fuss with the controls because of motor control issues isn't itself a safety issue? If everyone's certain only mechanics matter, fine!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin No, dual controls are not a legal requirement (at least not in the sort of light airplanes that it sounds like OP is talking about.) They're there mostly for purposes of flight instruction. It's probably cheaper to just design and certify the plane with two sets of controls than to design and certify both dual and solo control variants. The cost of the physical extra hardware for the second set of controls is completely negligible in the context of aircraft design. These are not mass consumer products built in the tens of millions where cents matter.

Comment: Seems to me that a person should learn to obey orders of those in authority regarding life and death situations before being allowed to board an aircraft in a crew member's seat, regardless of how excited they are to do so or how young they are.  I mean, cart before the horse?

Comment: @reirab I don't doubt that facts of what you say… that this isn't a legal requirement for light aircraft, and dual controls are mostly for instruction.

At risk of being shot down off Topic, I suggest it might well be cheaper to design and certify a plane with only with two sets of controls but design and certification isn't the point; only potential profit from extended production and sales.

Won't solo- planes cost thousands less than dual-control variants?

Comment: @java-addict301 yes, a person _should_ learn to obey orders, but not all people _can_ do so. No malicious harm in intent is involved, but those with motor control or emotional issues may simply flail out of pure delight, causing issues when piloting an aircraft. It seems to me a better solution would be to go up in a 4-seater and put the passenger in the back where such unintentional movements wouldn't be detrimental to flight safety.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No there isn't until you get to transport category airplanes that have dual redundant control path systems, with left/right control disconnect systems, to cater to system mechanical jam cases.

A few airplanes have control yokes that can be moved to either pilot's side or the passenger's side. The DeHavilland Beaver and Beech Bonanza are like that. When the yoke is on your side, the passenger only has rudder pedals.

On most GA airplanes with dual controls, they are always connected together, so the only way to keep the passenger's hands off is to remove the control itself from the airplane, and you'll sometimes see airplanes with the right control column removed, like planes used to drop jumpers, or planes never used for dual instruction, like bush planes, so they just want the column out of the way.

On tandem airplanes like a Cub, the control stick just goes into a socket retained by a bolt or pip pin, and frequently you'll see the passenger seat's stick removed from the socket to preclude any funny business.

In the end, if you're really worried about that sort of thing, I'd worry more about a passenger in your car that waits until a truck is approaching on a 2 lane highway and reaches across and yanks the steering wheel when the time is right.  Nothing you can do about that, and it's lights out in a few milliseconds.

In the plane, you'd have more of a fighting chance, especially if you had some altitude.  And if that was to happen somehow, there is a trick I learned when instructing in gliders to deal with students that freeze on controls - you choke them, either grabbing the throat with both hands, or a little karate chop to the front of the throat.  They'll let go (fortunately I never had to actually try it).

Comment: I've always thought about a non-pilot that would instinctively hit the left rudder pedal on landing as if trying to hit the brake on a car.  Seems like a very likely scenario.

Comment: My wife does that lol. I normally brief pax to keep their feet away from the pedals.

Comment: Hopefully you don't apply John's "little trick" to her...

Comment: Somehow I've got the mental image of "Karate chop to the throat" showing up as a line item in the QRH under "panicking PIC".

Comment: Instructing in a Schwietzer 2-33, you are hunched right up behind the student and you can easily reach their neck.  Other two seaters like a Blanik or Puchatz, you can't really reach unless you release your harness.  The neck is one spot where any kind of physical disturbance you can apply will make someone instinctively let go of what they're doing and reach for it.

Answer (score 8):

Many tandem two-seaters have an easily detached rear (or in some cases front) control stick.  Combine this with a simple rudder pedal cover, and a passenger is locked out of all controls other than throttle.  For aircraft built with this option, there is no regulatory effect from detaching the removable stick.

Next step up is a central stick (found in some side by side two-seaters) or throw-over yoke, most commonly seen in Beechcraft Bonanzas.  The Bonanza versions with this setup also had folding rudder pedals, so a passenger in a front seat would again have no controls other than power lever.  Built/certified this way, so FAA doesn't care what configuration you fly in (BTW, the Bonanza throw-over isn't readily switched in flight, making this version less desirable for instruction).

Plenty of homebuilt two-seaters have been constructed with single controls -- registered as experimental anyway, as long as it passed an inspection in the setup you'll be flying, good to go.

Now, if you start altering a certificated airframe by disabling or removing primary controls from the second seat, you will start to run into regulatory questions, but there are so many other options that don't require this that I'd handle it on a case by case basis -- if you own an airplane and want to take this enthusiastic disable teen on a flight, you should consult your local airframe mechanic and inspector.